# Laravel: catch HTTP request on artisan command test case

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-artisan

I've developed a Laravel console command that makes a HTTP request to an external API.
In the feature test, I want to check that the correct URL has been called.

The problem is that in the feature test I'm not able to catch the request made from the command.

Below an example of the code of the artisan command:

```php
// ...
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class SyncGamificationAccount extends Command
{
    // ...

    public function handle()
    {
        Http::get('http://example.com/api/some-endpoint');

        $this->info("Done :)");

        return 0;
    }

}
```

Please find below the code of the feature test:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

// ...

    /** @test */
    public function the_command_console_should_make_the_request()
    {
        Http::fake();

        $resp = $this->artisan('users:update-from-api');

        $expectedUrl = 'http://example.com/api/some-endpoint';

        Http::assertSent(
            function ($request) use ($expectedUrl) {
                dd('not triggered at all');
                return $request->url() == $expectedUrl;
            }
        );
    }
```

When I run the tests I get the following output:

```sh
1) Tests\Feature\Console\UsersUpdateFromApiTest::the_command_console_should_make_the_request
An expected request was not recorded.
Failed asserting that false is true.

/srv/http/laravel-prj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/Factory.php:223
/srv/http/laravel-prj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:261
/srv/http/laravel-prj/tests/Feature/Console/UsersUpdateFromApiTest.php:61

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

It seems like the block of code above within `Http::assertSent(...)` is not triggered at all since no API request has been intercepted; in fact when running the test, the die and dump `dd('not triggered at all');` is not shown.

I used lots of times `Http::fake();` and `Http::assertSent` but it seems like for the console command it doesn't work as usual.

Note that when running my command `php artisan users:update-from-api` it makes correctly the request.

Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: Show pls your command - Http::fake only works if you use Http facade to make request

Comment: The command is quite long, I'm working to make it short and I'll edit the question soon. In the feature-test and in command I use `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;`

Comment: I just found out that `Http::assertSent` does not catch the request. Instead, `Http::spy()` catches the http request... I didn't understand why...

Comment: Yes, that question was made by me and, if you look in one of the commented of the only answer, I thanked the author of the answer saying that `Http::spy()` helped me with this issue. I post below the solution.

Answer (score 0):

After trying and trying, I found out that `Http::assertSent` does not catch the request; instead, `Http::spy()` catches the http request.

> **Note:** This happened only on command line testing for me.

```php
    /** @test */
    public function the_command_console_should_make_the_request()
    {
        Http::fake();

        $resp = $this->artisan('users:update-from-api');

        $expectedUrl = 'http://example.com/api/some-endpoint';

        Http::spy()
            ->expects('get')
            ->with($expectedUrl)
            ->once();
    }
```

Comment: Please do not use answers for comments or asking for more. Here a suggestion: If you answer on the previous contribution (if applicable) this might gather more attraction. Also adding comments there.